# Вывести на PHP график работы, начиная с 1 числа

Tags: php

Подскажите, как вывести на PHP график работы, начиная с 1 числа сутки через двое. Причем, если день попадает на выходной, то переносим его на ближайший следующий понедельник и далее снова сутки через двое.
Пробую так, но выводит то не с 1 числа то не 1 через 2, а 2 через 2.

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
function isWorkDay($num) {
    return ($num % 4) < 2;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
    if (isWorkDay($i)) {
        echo $i . '+';
        echo PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $i;
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем тут функции isWeekend и isWorkDay, если они не используются?

Comment: isWeekend я написал для определения выходной день или нет, а isWorkDay - рабочий день определяет, по сути в ней и идет логика опроеделения графика сутки через двое. Просто так как с опоредедением верных дат у меня не получилось еще, то до опроеделения выходнйо или нет дело не дошло

Comment: Вот такой вариант я пытался использовтаь, оттуда у меня функция isWorkDay пришла:

for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
    if (isWorkDay($i)) {
        echo('<td>Р</td>');
    } else {
        echo('<td>В</td>');
    }
}

Comment: испарвил в вопросе с использованием функции

Comment: а какая логика в функции isWorkDay? Да и зачем она вообще нужна, если можно просто прибавлять сразу три дня, и если случился выходной, то брать понедельник и оттуда считать по три дня.

Comment: Так если бы я сам разобрался я бы тут не спрашивал))) Помогите кодом, как выполнить мою задачу

Comment: Вы же какую-то логику придумали, когда написали функцию isWorkDay. Какая она? Вы не можете объяснить свой собственный код?

Comment: @Batyabest `($num % 4) < 2` -- это не сутки через двое. Остаток от деления на 4 может быть 0, 1, 2 и 3. Получается двое суток через двое.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала решите задачу без учёта выходных. Сутки через двое это каждый третий день, каждый день кратный трём. Чтобы понять, что число кратно трём, надо взглянуть на остаток от деления на 3.

```php
function isWorkDay($day int): bool {
    return $day % 3 === 0;
}
```

Теперь надо добавить выходные. Функцию проверки вы написали, но как ей воспользоваться, чтобы перенести рабочий день? Если рабочий день выпал на выходной, можно просто сбросить счётчик рабочих дней. Получается, что дни месяца и счётчик рабочих дней это не одна, а две переменные.

```php
$fdm = new DateTimeImmutable('first day of this month midnight');
$workingDays = [];
$wDay = 0;
for ($day = 0; $day < $fdm->format('t'); ++$day) {
    if ($wDay % 3 === 0) {
        $d = $fdm->add(new DateInterval('P' . $day . 'D'));
        if ($d->format('N') < 6) { // будни
            $workingDays[] = $d;    
        } else { // выходные
            $wDay = 0;
            continue;
        }
    }

    ++$wDay;
}

var_dump($workingDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще график очень странный, кроме первой недели он всегда сводится к понедельнику и четвергу. Т.е. если график действительно по таким условиям, то в принципе вы можете проверять только первую неделю:
Понедельник - Рабочие дни Понедельник и Четверг

Вторник - Вторник и Пятница

Среда, Четверг, Пятница - они же

далее каждая неделя Понедельник и Четверг

Если нужно решение в лоб, то код привел

```
<?php
$date_begin = '2022-09-23';
$days       = 20;

$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date_begin);
$workday  = 2;
echo "date\ti\tday\twork" . PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 0; $i < $days; ++$i)
{
    ++$workday;
    if (date('N', strtotime($datetime->format('d-m-Y'))) < 6 and $workday > 2)
    {
        $workday = 0;
    }
    echo $datetime->format('d-m-Y') . "\t" . $i . "\t" . date('N', strtotime($datetime->format('d-m-Y')));
    if ($workday == 0)
        echo '+';
    echo PHP_EOL;
    $datetime->modify('+1 days');
}
```